# MTDF FILTER plugin not showing the result in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on this website: [link](https://asiatic.endroid1.com/shop/), and I'm using the **MTDF FILTER plugin** in Wordpress.

When I select any filter for price or width, it is not showing the products' result.

[image]

[image]

If anybody want to needs access I can provide it.

Any ideas on what could be causing that?

Comment: https://wp-filter.com/step-by-step/

Comment: plugin link; https://wp-filter.com/step-by-step/